# Disable Ethernet connection on Mac terminal

Tags: terminal, osx, lan

I am trying to write an alias for disabling ethernet connection and use the wifi using a command line. I can't access stackoverflow.com and other sites using ethernet due to corporate policies. Is there a way to disable ethernet connection so that my laptop defaults back to wifi so I can browse?

Comment: unplug the ethernet cable?

Comment: thats exactly what I am trying to avoid

Answer (score 2):

For mac, I ended up doing `networksetup -setnetworkserviceenabled "Ethernet" off`, where 'Ethernet' is the name of network service I got from `networksetup -listallnetworkservices`

Comment: This works perfectly. I'll create a shell alias for this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not command line, but you can change the routing weight for the interfaces by changing the order in the Network Settings page.

Click on the cog under the list of devices and select "Set Service Order". If you drag the WiFi adapter above the Ethernet adapter it should route via the WiFi first, then fall back to the Ethernet.

Assuming you have a vaguely sensible network setup this should work without needing to flip things back and forth.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This will cause my localhost to not work(service calls will fail due to not hitting the company network)

Comment: Sounds like you don't have sensible routing/subnet masks for your lan or you need to set up http proxy on the work lan. I'm assuming the WiFi is teathered to your phone and you are breaking company policy by using it then

Comment: Not exactly, there is a company's wifi network that allows you to browse. The ethernet connection doesn't